# laravel query builder without raw?

Tags: laravel, builder

i have a query with this code

```
return $query
                ->select([
                    'lineofpro AS pabrik_line',
                    'date AS tanggal',
                    DB::raw('ROUND((100*(COUNT( CASE WHEN `tabTravel Card`.qcresu = "Pass" THEN 1 ELSE NULL END ))/count(`tabTravel Card`.lineofpro))) AS lar_percentage'),
                    DB::raw("ROUND( IFNULL(SUM(`tabTravel Card`.finga),0) / ( count(`tabTravel Card`.lineofpro) * 200) * 1000000) AS finger_a"),
                    DB::raw("ROUND( IFNULL(SUM(`tabTravel Card`.fingb),0) / ( count(`tabTravel Card`.lineofpro) * 200) * 1000000) AS finger_b"),
                    DB::raw("ROUND( IFNULL(SUM(`tabTravel Card`.fingc),0) / ( count(`tabTravel Card`.lineofpro) * 200) * 1000000) AS finger_c"),
                    DB::raw("ROUND( IFNULL(SUM(`tabTravel Card`.fingd),0) / ( count(`tabTravel Card`.lineofpro) * 200) * 1000000) AS finger_d"),
                    DB::raw("ROUND( IFNULL(SUM(`tabTravel Card`.finge),0) / ( count(`tabTravel Card`.lineofpro) * 200) * 1000000) AS finger_e"),
                    DB::raw("ROUND( IFNULL(SUM(`tabTravel Card`.crotchf),0) / ( count(`tabTravel Card`.lineofpro) * 200) * 1000000) AS crotch_f"),
                    DB::raw("ROUND( IFNULL(SUM(`tabTravel Card`.crotchg),0) / ( count(`tabTravel Card`.lineofpro) * 200) * 1000000) AS crotch_g"),
                    DB::raw("ROUND( IFNULL(SUM(`tabTravel Card`.crotchh),0) / ( count(`tabTravel Card`.lineofpro) * 200) * 1000000) AS crotch_h"),
                    DB::raw("ROUND( IFNULL(SUM(`tabTravel Card`.crotchi),0) / ( count(`tabTravel Card`.lineofpro) * 200) * 1000000) AS crotch_i"),
                    DB::raw("ROUND( IFNULL(SUM(`tabTravel Card`.palmj),0) / ( count(`tabTravel Card`.lineofpro) * 200) * 1000000) AS palm_j"),
                    DB::raw("ROUND( IFNULL(SUM(`tabTravel Card`.cuffk),0) / ( count(`tabTravel Card`.lineofpro) * 200) * 1000000) AS cuff_k"),
                    DB::raw("ROUND( IFNULL(SUM(`tabTravel Card`.totalpin),0) / ( count(`tabTravel Card`.lineofpro) * 200) * 1000000) AS total_pinhole"),
                ])
                ->where([
                    ['date', '>=', $beginDate],
                    ['date', '<=', $endDate],
                    $this->generatePlanCodeFilter($plan, $line),
                ])
                ->groupBy([
                    'lineofpro',
                    'date',
                ]);
```

is it possible to query this without DB::raw?
i try to create dynamic query
but using an array to return the select value with DB::raw will only return '' string

Answer (score 0):

You can define your fields as accessors and move your calculation logic there.

Then you can build the query using Eloquent.

Ex:

```php
public function getTotalPinholeAttribute()
{
    // calculation logic here
}
```

You can read more about accessors here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

Comment: i have a calculation on that column. not just get the value

Comment: Nothing is preventing you from doing calculations there.

Comment: If you can share your `model` and `migration`, I might be able to help with the logic too.

Comment: dont have the migration for that model cause i trying to get the data from other application. im trying to create an API
this is the structur of the table https://pastebin.com/mLbN3uZw.
can you make example of the function above?